# How Split sentence In Java with "" caractére

Tags: java

How Can I **split** sentence like :

```
aaaa "00000036" dddd "Raison aaaMotif" a été enregistrée avec succès.
```

to get **00000036** number !!!?

```
MsgOffreAdded =.Span_MSG_Id_Offre_added.getText();
/*
* split to get code 
*/
String[] arr = MsgOffreAdded.split("\\"|\\""");
System.out.println("code new offre de prix" + arr[1]);
MsgOffreAdded = arr[1];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You mean extract that specific number (which wouldn't mean much) or *any* number? Also, from where?

Comment: i want to get  this number alone 00000036

Comment: to use it after

Comment: I am trying to split sentence to get 00000036 in separate char

Comment: Please also post your code

Comment: i add my code but i dont know how to do for split to get number!

Comment: Ok, What is in MsgOffreAdded ?

Comment: MsgOffreAdded=aaaa "00000036" dddd "Raison aaaMotif" a été enregistrée avec succès.

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is :

```
String str = "aaaa \"00000036\" dddd \"Raison aaaMotif\" a été enregistrée avec succès.";
String []splitStr = str.split("\"");
System.out.println(splitStr[0]); //print -> aaaa
System.out.println(splitStr[1]); //print -> 00000036
```

As you can see, In the above snippet I've use `\"someString"\` in my code to have **multiple** double quotes in my `String`!

Happy coding!

Comment: Its Useful for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in the number, you can also do `str.replaceAll("^.*\"([0-9]+)\".*$", "$1")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String stringToSplit = "aaaa 00000036 dddd Raison aaaMotif a été enregistrée avec succès.";

    String numberString  = stringToSplit.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    int number = Integer.valueOf(numberString);
    Toast.makeText(this,number,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

that toast will show 00000036 ..
have fun